# How to fix variable string in Python from serial being misaligned in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pyserial

I am trying to make a Python Tkinter GUI that sends a 1 char value (in this case 'A') and gets a respective message "Warm peristaltic pump speed set to 25 rpm". I am unable to change the return string. However, as seen in the pictures, when I display the string sent from serial, the string gets cut off on the top. When I try to update the label using a random string variable, it displays fine.

I would like the readBack string in the code to display correctly. As of now, I do not have any noticeable errors being output.

I am not very experienced in Python Serial or Tkinter, but I do want to learn. I was hoping someone could explain why this happens and how to fix it.

Thank you.

For sending serial data, I have

```
self.ser = serial.Serial(timeout = 1)

self.wppsLabel = QLabel(self.serialcommandframe, text="", height=1, width = 25, anchor='w')

def sendAndReadSerial(self, cmd);
        frame = bytearray(cmd.encode())
        self.ser.write(frame)
        readBack = self.ser.read(99)
        return str(readBack.decode('utf-8'))

def sendWppsCommand(self):
    cmd = 'A'
    readBack = self.sendAndReadSerial(cmd)
    self.wppsLabel['text'] = readBack
    #self.wppsLabel['text'] = "TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING "
```

This is the code for QLabel:

```
class QLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["fg"] = 'black'
        kwargs["font"] = 'Arial 10 bold'
        Label.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is how I want the data to look when updated:
[image]

Here is how it is being displayed right now. As you can see the tops of the characters are cut.
[image]

Comment: Umm...`QLabel` is not from `tkinter` but from `PyQt`..?

Comment: Sorry I made my own Label called QLabel based on tkinter. I just edited it for simplicity.

Comment: Then the way you made the label might be the problem, anyway try remove `anchor` option and also post an example that we could run by. Also what does `print(readBack)` show

Comment: print(readBack) shows: "Warm peristaltic pump speed set to 25 rpm" As of now I can not test the serial, but I was wondering if there was a major mistake in my code. Thank you for the suggestion with "anchor". The code runs fine unless the hardware board is connected.

Comment: Yea because I do not sea any reason why it would change like this. What about the class, show your `QLabel` class code

Comment: I just updated the question to include the QLabel code. Half of this was written by someone else a year ago, so there could be something outdated.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would look like this, are you using `place` or something?

Comment: Does the string have more than one line, or does it end in a newline?

Comment: I am not using place. There is no newline. It is a single-line string.

Comment: Can you also `repr(readBack)`, just to be sure and next time when replying to a comment, use @username to notify the person. Or you will be left unattended.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Thank you! I haven't used Stack Overflow a lot. The help is greatly appreciated.